# SharePoint 2013 "Runtime Error"

Tags: document-library, web-config, runtime

I'm receiving this error when trying to check-in a document in a document library (it's only occurring on this document library).

---

[image: Runtime Error]

---

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   You must fill out all required properties before checking in this document. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: You must fill out all required properties before checking in this document.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SPException: You must fill out all required properties before checking in this document.] Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Checkin.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +2194 System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +95 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2936

Comment: I can now see detailed error messages by reviewing each of the web.config files listed in the original post. Time to troubleshoot the actual error.

Comment: is there any metadata column associate with document library?

Answer (score 0):

The error prevent you check in on document library:

> You must fill out all required properties before checking in this
>   document

Can you try to fill all of the required fields before check in ?

The image you attached mean you didn't turn off the CustomError in all sites of farm and the web.config in folder 15. I guess there still have the sites that have `<customerror mode=On>`. So that we saw the error like this.